# HTML, issue with radio input within a table

Tags: html, css, radio-button, html-table

I modified a little bit the following code (to have a table having vertical header):

http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/Fapif

My output is:

https://jsfiddle.net/av2ptwqv/

my code is:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>
            Newsletter generator v2
        </title>
        <style>
.table-header-rotated {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.table-header-rotated td {
  width: 30px;
}
 .table-header-rotated th {
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
.table-header-rotated td {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
 .table-header-rotated th.rotate {
  height: 140px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
 .table-header-rotated th.rotate > div {
  -webkit-transform: translate(25px, 51px) rotate(315deg);
      -ms-transform: translate(25px, 51px) rotate(315deg);
          transform: translate(25px, 51px) rotate(315deg);
  width: 30px;
}
 .table-header-rotated th.rotate > div > span {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
.table-header-rotated th.row-header {
  padding: 0 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
    </style>
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    </head>
    <body>
 <table class="table-header-rotated">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <!-- First column header is not rotated -->
                <th></th>
                <!-- Following headers are rotated -->
                <th class="rotate">
                    <div><span>Column header 1</span></div>
                </th>
                <th class="rotate">
                    <div><span>Column header 2</span></div>
                </th>
                <th class="rotate">
                    <div><span>Column header 3</span></div>
                </th>
                <th class="rotate">
                    <div><span>Column header 4</span></div>
                </th>
                <th class="rotate">
                    <div><span>Column header 5</span></div>
                </th>
                <th class="rotate">
                    <div><span>Column header 6</span></div>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th class="row-header">Row header 1</th>
                <td>
                    <input checked="checked" name="column1[]" type="radio" value="row1-column1">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input checked="checked" name="column2[]" type="radio" value="row1-column2">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input name="column3[]" type="radio" value="row1-column3">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input name="column4[]" type="radio" value="row1-column4">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input name="column5[]" type="radio" value="row1-column5">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input name="column6[]" type="radio" value="row1-column6">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="row-header">Row header 2</th>
                <td>
                    <input name="column1[]" type="radio" value="row2-column1">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input name="column2[]" type="radio" value="row2-column2">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input checked="checked" name="column3[]" type="radio" value="row2-column3">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input checked="checked" name="column4[]" type="radio" value="row2-column4">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input name="column5[]" type="radio" value="row2-column5">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input name="column6[]" type="radio" value="row2-column6">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="row-header">Row header 3</th>
                <td>
                    <input name="column1[]" type="radio" value="row3-column1">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input name="column2[]" type="radio" value="row3-column2">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input name="column3[]" type="radio" value="row3-column3">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input name="column4[]" type="radio" value="row3-column4">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input checked="checked" name="column5[]" type="radio" value="row3-column5">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input checked="checked" name="column6[]" type="radio" value="row3-column6">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

My question is quite simple: so right now we can only have one unique choice per row, how can we turn this to have one unique choice not per row but per line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the radio buttons that should be grouped the same name. Like this:

```
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th class="row-header">Row header 1</th>
            <td><input checked="checked" name="line1[]" type="radio" value="row1-column1" /></td>
            <td><input name="line1[]" type="radio" value="row1-column2" /></td>
            <td><input name="line1[]" type="radio" value="row1-column3" /></td>
            <td><input name="line1[]" type="radio" value="row1-column4" /></td>
            <td><input name="line1[]" type="radio" value="row1-column5" /></td>
            <td><input name="line1[]" type="radio" value="row1-column6" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th class="row-header">Row header 2</th>
            <td><input name="line2[]" type="radio" value="row2-column1" /></td>
            <td><input name="line2[]" type="radio" value="row2-column2" /></td>
            <td><input checked="checked" name="line2[]" type="radio" value="row2-column3" /></td>
            <td><input name="line2[]" type="radio" value="row2-column4" /></td>
            <td><input name="line2[]" type="radio" value="row2-column5" /></td>
            <td><input name="line2[]" type="radio" value="row2-column6" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th class="row-header">Row header 3</th>
            <td><input name="line3[]" type="radio" value="row3-column1" /></td>
            <td><input name="line3[]" type="radio" value="row3-column2" /></td>
            <td><input name="line3[]" type="radio" value="row3-column3" /></td>
            <td><input name="line3[]" type="radio" value="row3-column4" /></td>
            <td><input checked="checked" name="line3[]" type="radio" value="row3-column5" /></td>
            <td><input name="line3[]" type="radio" value="row3-column6" /></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/av2ptwqv/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Radio input are grouped by `name` tag, and you can have only one selection by group. 
So what you have to do, is to give the same `name` tag at each radio input that are on the same line.

As easy as that.